# What is the difference between dual gauge and single gauge in voltage regulator IC?

Tags: power-supply, power, ldo, linear-regulator

I was looking at the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000449.pdf) of the L78S voltage regulator IC from STMicroelectronics. I saw a mention of dual gauge and single gauge. The dual gauge price is slightly more than single gauge. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Gauge" is to do with the thickness of the heatsink provided for the IC

So great. Since we know that the temperature generated in an IC is the limiting quanitity on the functioning of an IC, your IC is as good as the effectiveness of your heat sink. What does a heat sink do? It removes heat from the IC and passes it onto the surroundings. Since your heat sink is a metal, it transfers heat through 'conduction'. Assuming 1-D conduction, i.e., conduction in only one direction, the governing equation would be -

```
Q = kAΔT/l
```

where--> Q = Rate of heat transfer(here rate of heat removal)

A = Surface area of heat transfer(here heat sink surface area)

ΔT = Difference in temperature across conducting wall(here temperature diff. between IC and surroundings)

l = Thickness of wall(here the thickness of your heat sink)

As you can see, the rate of heat removal is inversely proportional to the thickness of the heat sink. Hence, a single gauge IC, with a lower heat sink thickness will lead to a more effective removal of heat and hence better performance.

Comment: Indeed it's the thickness of the heat spreader at the back of the chip. Parameter "f" in the mechanical data at the end of the datasheet.

Comment: Datasheet doesn't discriminate between single and double, in the thermal resistance, junction to case, at 5 degrees /watt. It's unlikely to be dominated by 1 mm of copper anyway! At 400 W/mK, 1 mm of copper, 5x5 mm, would contribute only 0.1 degrees/watt. Most of the resistance must be in the silicon, not the copper. Perhaps the thicker flange is better, allowing the heat to spread to a larger surface before meeting the heat sink grease etc.

Answer (score 2):

A thicker piece of metal conducts heat better than a thin piece.  The goal is to keep the on chip circuitry cooler. Heat is transferred out better with the thicker heat conductor.

Comment: That's the opposite of what Prakash is saying. Why do you think a thicker piece will *conduct* better?

Comment: It doesn't but it diffuses the heat on a larger surface for the interface layer between the transistor and the heat sink.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem counter intuitive that a thin heat sink would be better.  But it is perhaps why hot water radiators use thin aluminium radiating elements.  Prakash is saying that the heat transfer rate is faster.  A thinner heat sink would certainly heat up faster.  However, I'm not so sure that the thinner heat sink with the same dims as the thicker would have greater capacity to absorb and transfer heat better to the surrounding area.  In fact the thicker heat sink would have slightly larger surface area.